# Host a video, and have playback speed between 25% and 1,000%

Tags: youtube, html5-video, vimeo, video.js

Where should I host a video to be able to control playback rate from 25% speed all the way up to 1,000% speed (10x faster)?

[Controlling playback speed](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_playbackrate) is easy with HTML5 `<video>`. However I can't find a video host to support the speed range I need.

**Options I've considered:**

**Self-hosting**

One option is to host the video on my own servers. From what I've read this comes with a lot of complications, and it's preferred to host on existing services (Youtube, Vimeo, Brightcove, etc).

**Youtube**

I looked through the [YouTube video API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls), but it only has a certain range of playback rates that doesn't sound like it gets up to 1,000% speed. Although I own the videos, so maybe I have control over available playback rates them when I upload?

**Vimeo**

No playback rate controls.

**Brightcove**

API has a [function](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/src/js/player.js#L1805) for setting playback rate.  But also requires paying...

Comment: Can you clarify on the self-hosting complications you've found?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with download speed. A recording with my phone is approximately 2MB per second. So 10x speed playback would require 20MB download speed to keep up. Lower quality and encoding will drop the required speed, but you still need quite the connection.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to make use of [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) particularly with this example [here](http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube). It is possible that YouTube simply won't serve the content fast enough to run at 1,000% speed, however.

If that is the case, I do think that rolling on your own solution with the `<video>` element is easiest here, making use of any CDN service to serve your content. The caveat here is that you are restricted by browser support, though almost all modern browsers will support the `<video>` tag.

Comment: MediaElement can only support playback speed in HTML5 anyway, so you don't gain anything.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this is possible unless you use the HTML `<video>` element in a custom implementation. Even the Youtube API states:

> Even though the AS3 player supports playback rate controls, variable speeds are currently only supported in the HTML5 player.

At present (May 2015), your best bet is to create your own solution, since youtube seems use flash even on some browsers that support html5 videos, like my Opera 29 (though if I change my user-agent to chrome, it does serve the html5 player...). Most browsers can handle mp4, and you could encode the video at different playback speeds as a fallback if the `<video>` element isn't supported. At this point [`<video>` support is approaching 95% in the US](http://caniuse.com/#search=video), so a fallback may not be necessary depending on your audience.

Another point in favor of using your own solution is that youtube seems to only support playback up to 2x speed (200%).

The biggest problem with hosting your own video that isn't solved by the `<video>` element as far as I've seen is the load on the server. Using a CDN would probably solve this problem. Please note that my laptop can't play smooth hd video (well, DVD quality, I don't have a lot of videos to test with) served from my own machine at more than 2x, so unless you're using very small videos you might find 10x impractical.

[HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) has a good overview of setting up the `<video>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can host the media files on AWS S3 (either on AWS itself or compatible services such as Dreamhost). S3 solves some of the FTP issues with self-hosting of media files such as uploading large files, versioning, etc., and it might be a reasonable compromise when complete media-player control is a must.

If the above solution is not feasible then you can:

- Transcode the media upfront in several most-relevant speeds. Changing the playback speed will mean switching to a different movie.
- Provide the option to download the files or relevant chunks so the user will use a local player (e.g. VLC) to "play" with the media.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with Vimeo, the Pro version anyway.
I go to the hosted video, Video File and Access your video files.
There are links there to video files that can be use as the source for the HTML5 video.

```
<video id="video" src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/1278xxx.hd.mp4?s=xxx&profile_id=119">
```

After that it's using jQuery to get a handle on the video

```
var video = $("video")[0];
```

And changing playback rate is

```
video.playbackRate = 0.25;
```

Might run into some security issues as anyone with the link can now download the file with a Right Click and Save As.

Comment: @jocshea - most streaming services supports 0.25x - 4x.  I need something that goes beyond 4x. Does Vimeo do this?